# C++ linker error using Boost Thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

Attempting to build a standard Boost::thread example I found on the internet, I get multiple errors thrown by the Boost header file thread_data.hpp, which I don't link to directly but which I presume gets linked by Boost. (I also get the same errors in my actual program, but I am using the example code to ensure it's not a problem with my code.)

Here is the example code I found in a boost::thread tutorial:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <boost/date_time.hpp>

    void workerFunc()
    {
        boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
        std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

        // Pretend to do something useful...
        boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
        std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;
        boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);
        std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;
        workerThread.join();
        std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is my build command:

```
    mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\projects\boost\lib  -o bin\Debug\Guardian.exe obj\Debug\Scratch.o    -lboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-1_53 -lboost_date_time-mgw47-mt-1_53 -lboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_53 -lboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_53
```

(Notice that I *am* linking the *boost.thread* library.)

Here is the first error thrown:

```
    C:\projects\boost\include\boost-1_53\boost\thread\win32\thread_data.hpp|123|undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE'|
```

In CodeBlocks I get pointed to line 123 of the header file thread_data.hpp as the source of the error:

```
    //#if defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_INTERRUPTIONS
            , interruption_handle(create_anonymous_event(detail::win32::manual_reset_event,detail::win32::event_initially_reset))
            , interruption_enabled(true)
```

Have I forgotten to link a library? I've been using Boost without problems, until now I'm trying to use the thread library. I'm new to Boost and don't know what could be causing the error.

Comment: I've just built your example from the command line with MinGW-32, and it builds just fine. I've used: `g++ main.cpp -IC:\Dev\lib2\mingw32\boost\boost1530 -LC:\Dev\lib2\mingw32\boost\boost1530\lib -o main.exe -lboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-d-1_53 -lboost_date_time-mgw47-mt-d-1_53 -lboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_53 -lboost_thread-mgw47-mt-d-1_53`. have you tried building it from the command line?

Comment: Another question - are you linking statically or dinamically? If you're linking statically, you might need to `#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB`

Comment: Building it from the command line, using the compiler command I mentioned above, produces the same error, only in the command console rather than in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Could it be something wrong with my Boost libraries? I built them up myself and I may have done something wrong that is only now showing up.

Comment: Have you saved the output from when you built Boost (I usually redirect it to a file with `> boost_install.log 2>&1`)? If you did, you can take a look at it, and see if there were any errors during the build. I never had many problems with Boost, but I know from experience with building Qt that a successful end to the build process doesn't mean everything went smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'll rebuild my Boost libraries and try again.

Comment: @user2109130 Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try add -lpthread to the linker.